# Cant install libnet-server-perl on Debian 8x

Tags: linux, perl, debian, virtual-machine

I keep getting these after Depends: in terminal.

```
libnet-server-perl but it is not installable
```

and

```
libipic-shareable-perl but it is not installable
```

I have found many different posts on how to install these and none have worked on **Debian 8x**.  I have both packages downloaded and they include `.tar.gz` and `tar.xz` but can't not figure out how to install them so they are recognized.

Answer (score 0):

`libnet-server-perl, libipc-shareable-perl` :

```
# apt-get update && apt-get install libnet-server-perl libipc-shareable-perl
```

https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=jessie&searchon=names&keywords=libnet-server-perl

https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=jessie&keywords=libipc-shareable-perl